# The macOS “say” utility does not work for non-root users in Sierra

Tags: macos, tmux, say

I have a program that invokes the `say` command line utility on my mac that stopped working after I upgraded to macOS Sierra.

When I try to run the `/usr/bin/say` command from the command line, it just hangs (requires a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>).

If I run as root, it works just fine. I can’t figure out what changed in Sierra that would cause this odd behavior.

Comment: It turned out that it was a compatibility issue with tmux.  I'm still unclear why but the command runs normally when run outside of a tmux session.

Answer (score 1):

It was a compatibility issue with tmux.  Works as expected outside of tmux sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `reattach-to-user-namespace` program installed and add lines like the following to your ~/.tmux.conf, when you run "say" utility inside of a tmux session.

```
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace

# In .tmux.conf:
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"

# To kill your existing tmux server (and everything running “inside” it!):
tmux kill-server
```

Some useful links:
1. Mac "say" not working in tmux session - https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/716
2. tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard - https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard