# How to run `say` at a specified time with `at` on macOS?

Tags: macos, launchctl, at, say

Running `echo "say hello" | at now+1` on macOS should enqueue a task to be executed one minute in the future: saying hello. Issuing `say hello` works fine, as does `echo "touch a-file" | at now+1`, but the combination does not.

I believe that the runtime environment on which `launchd` executes `atrun` (the `at` daemon) is restricted and cannot complete the speech synthesis instructed by `say`. However, I cannot easily determine if this is the case.

What is the problem?

Comment: I'm also trying to get this to work. I figured out that `echo say hello | at next minute` responds `Open speech channel failed: -915`. But I'm not sure what to do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got it working, and I found a lengthy explanation of what is going on.

Apparently it's the same problem as this one: [The macOS “say” utility does not work for non-root users in Sierra](https://superuser.com/questions/1137794/the-macos-say-utility-does-not-work-for-non-root-users-in-sierra)

Lengthy explanation: https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard

After running `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace` I can now run `echo reattach-to-user-namespace say hello | at next minute` and it works!

To simplify my life I wrote a small wrapper and placed it in `~/bin` which I added first in my `$PATH`. All it does is to call the original `say` with all the supplied arguments, but "reattached". As far as I can tell, reattaching when it isn't needed doesn't seem to do any harm.

`~/bin/say`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
reattach-to-user-namespace /usr/bin/say $@
```

Now I can just write `echo say -v Nora Rimember att de kettel is ånn de ståuv | at now +5 minutes` and it works!